# How to get contents of a .config file using ConfigurationManager.GetSection(columnsSectionName) without altering the sections' order?

Tags: c#, configurationmanager, idictionary

In my config section I have the following:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog"/>
    <section name="NFeColumns" type="System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler" />
    <section name="CTeColumns" type="System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler" />
  </configSections>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="csv.separator" value=";" />
    <add key="infNFe.columns" value="NFeColumns"/>
    <add key="infCte.columns" value="CTeColumns"/>
    <add key="infNFe.filename" value=".\Extracted\NFeCollection.csv"/>
    <add key="infCte.filename" value=".\Extracted\CTeCollection.csv"/>
  </appSettings>

  <NFeColumns>
    <add key="infNFe.Id"  value="Id" />
    <add key="ide.cUF"    value="cUF" />
    <add key="dest.CNPJ"  value="CNPJ" />
    <add key="dest.xNome" value="xNome" />
    <add key="det.nItem"  value="nItem" />
    <add key="prod.cProd" value="cProd" />
    <add key="prod.xProd" value="xProd" />
    <add key="IPI.cEnq"   value="cEnq" />
  </NFeColumns>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>

</configuration>
```

I want to catch the values from   and put in a IDictionary in the same order as the configuration file. I`m doing this:

```
 string columnsSectionName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[colFileName + ".columns"];
            IDictionary columns = (IDictionary)ConfigurationManager.GetSection(columnsSectionName);
```

However, I`m geting the <NFeColumns> in a totally different order, and I can`t figure out why. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConfigurationManager.GetSection` returns an instance of [HashTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx). Items in a hash table won't be stored in the order they are inserted. You will have to manually order them.